# codeigniter restful api illegal string offset in several fields

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, postman

I keep on getting this error in my codeigniter micro app restful api. When I post an item only the first letter is get saved with status code 400 being displayed.

here is my model file:

```
class Cities_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function save($city)
    {
        $this->db->set($this->setCity($city, null))->insert('cities');

        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return $this->db->insert_id;
        }
      return null;
    }

    public function update($id, $city)
    {
        $this->db->set($this->setCity($city))->where('id')->update('cities');
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() === 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private function setCity($city)
    {
        return array(
            'id' => $city['id'],
            'name' => $city['name']
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->db->set($this->setCity($city,null))->insert('cities');` change this to `$this->db->insert('cities', array('city'=>$city));`

Comment: Thanks but you have not included the function setCity which is the one containing the data to be inserted.

Comment: you have extended `CI_Model` so it doesn't have any setter-getter methods, and you actually passing city value to the function.

Comment: The HTTP 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server could not understand the request due to invalid syntax. The client should not repeat this request without modification.

Comment: just I see your `setCity` function below. `$this->db->insert('cities',$this->setCity(array('city'=>$city,'id'=> null)));`

Comment: thanks but it worked. however there is another error " Undefined property: CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$insert_id"

Comment: I solved it. Thanks so much buddy for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see `setCity` function treat `$city` variable as array. So you need to pass array to `setCity` function.

```
class Cities_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function save($city)
    {
        $this->db->insert('cities',$this->setCity(array('name'=>$cit‌​y,'id'=> null)));

        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
      return null;
    }

    public function update($id, $city)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id)->update('cities',$this->setCity(array('name'=>$cit‌​y,'id'=> $id)));

        if ($this->db->affected_rows() === 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private function setCity($city)
    {
        return array(
            'id' => $city['id'],
            'name' => $city['name']
        );
    }
}
```

another thing is, Codeignitor having method `insert_id()` to know last insert id.

Comment: thanks so much buddy.it worked. kindly allow me to ask you explain how to update data with put because it is not working as I expect.

Comment: I am just getting status code 400 with no changes on update

Comment: any ideas please

Comment: it would be great if you can post both

Comment: any response yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php

  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

   require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

  class Cities extends REST_Controller{

public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('cities_model');
}    
public function index_get(){
   $cities=$this->cities_model->get();
   if(!is_null($cities))
   {
   $this->response(array('response'=>$cities),200);
   }
   else
   {
   $this->response(array('error'=>'cities cannot be found...'),404);
   }

    }

     public function find_get($id){
   if(!$id)
   {
   $this->respose(null,400);
   }
   $cit=$this->cities_model->get($id);
   if(!is_null($cit))
   {
   $this->response(array('response'=> $cit),200);
   }
   else{
   $this->response(array('error'=> 'data could not be found...'),404);

   }
   }

    public function index_post(){

// Use validation library, instead of checking just for value.
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('city','City','trim|required');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    // send back list of validation errors.
    $this->response($this->validation_errors(),REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}

$id=$this->cities_model->save($this->post('city'));
if(!is_null($id))
{
    $this->response(array('response'=> $id),REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}
else
{
    $this->response(array('error'=> 'sorry, data could not be saved...'),REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}
 }
 public function index_put(){
// for put you need to pass id as parameter 

// Use validation library, instead of checking just for value.
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('id','ID','trim|required|integer');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('city','City','trim|required');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    // send back list of validation errors.
    $this->response($this->validation_errors(),REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}

$update=$this->cities_model->update($this->post('id'),$this->post('city'));
if(!is_null($update))
{
    $this->response(array('response' => 'content updated successfully'),REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}
else
{
    $this->response(array('error'=> 'sorry, technical error occurred, please try again later...'), REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
     }
     public function index_delete($id){
   if(!$id)
   {
   $this->response(null,400);
   }
   $del=$this->cities_model->delete($id);
   if(!is_null($del))
   {
   $this->response(array('response'=> 'item successfully deleted'),200);

   }
   else{
   $this->response(array('error'=> 'delete operations could not be done...'),400);
   }
    }
    }
```

here is the model file:

```
 <?php
  class Cities_model extends CI_Model
 {
 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();

 }
 public function get($id=null)
 {
 if(!is_null($id))
 {
  $query=$this->db->select('*')->from('cities')->where('id',$id)->get();
  if($query->num_rows()===1)
   {
   return $query->row_array();
   }
   return null;
   }
   $sql=$this->db->select('*')->from('cities')->get();
   if($sql->num_rows()>0)
  {
   return $sql->result_array();
  }
  return null;
  }
  public function save($city)
 {
 $this->db->insert('cities', array('name'=>$city));
 if($this->db->affected_rows()>0)
 {
 return $this->db->insert_id();
 }
 return null;
 }
 public function update($id, $city)
 {
    $this->db->where('id',$id)->update('cities',$this->setCity(array('name'=>$cit‌​y,'id'=> $id)));

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() === 1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
 private function setCity($city)
 {
 return array('id'=>$city['id'],
         'name'=>$city['name']
         );
 }
 public function delete($id)
 { 
 $this->db->where('id',$id)->delete('cities');
 if($this->db->affected_rows()===1)
  {
 return true;
 }
  return false;
  }
  }
```

Comment: that is the whole controller